# Get modularity class from gephi imported graph using networkx

Tags: python, mongodb, networkx, modularity, gephi

I've imported a graphml from Gephi to NetworkX.

`G = nx.read_graphml(r"pah\EXPORTCM0606.graphml")`

In Gephi I had calculated modularity class obtaining 6 main communities and I would like to get these communities now in NetworkX in order to obtain the most frequent words in their tweets.
So my question is double:
How can I get these modularity class communities already calculated in Gephi from G using NetworkX?

How can I then match the graph I generate, from MongoDB with the tweets and the imported graph from Gephi?
Code to generate the graph from MongoDB with the tweets:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.CuartoMilenio06062021

import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

for result in db.tweets.find():
     uid = result['user']['screen_name']
     G.add_node(uid) 
       
     #Attributes
     if 'quoted_status' in result and 'text' in result: 
         node_attrs = {uid: {"text": result['quoted_status']['text']}}
         nx.set_node_attributes(G, node_attrs)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you a very simple example that I hope it will work.
Having used used the network `Power Grid.gml`, included with Gephi, I calculated the modularity inside Gephi, exported the graph as `graphml` and read with `networkx`.

```
# read the network
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_graphml('Power Grid.graphml')
```

Then giving something like `G.nodes[<id>]`, will list all node attributes.
Below an example for the node with id `0`. When accessing the node with:

```
G.nodes['0']
```

it gives us the following:

```
{'label': '0',
 'Modularity Class': 3,
 'size': 10.0,
 'r': 0,
 'g': 0,
 'b': 0,
 'x': -445.68524,
 'y': 141.22151}
```

Please note that the node has an attribute named `'Modularity Class'`, that is the _modularity class computed by Gephi?. One can then eg. iterate the nodes and access *Modularity class* like in the following:

```py
# Print the modularity class for each node
for u in G.nodes():
    print(G.nodes[u]['Modularity Class'])
```